# How to change the db2 user name for Worklight?

Tags: security, db2, ibm-mobilefirst

By default, installing Worklight (V6.2) with DB2 use the service ID db2admin.  For security reasons, what is the procedure of creating a new user id for support after installation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that your DB2 user?

If you want to use your own or change it, you need to do that in your DB2 database UI...
Follow the manual installation instructions for 6.2: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/t_config_DB2_DB_manually_for_wladmin.html

Comment: Thanks. We don't have that user yet - but want to create a new user instead of using db2admin.  Instead of manually creating new databases - is that possible to use the existing databases but just grant the right to other users?

Answer (score 0):

DB2 users are operating system users, so you need to create a new user on the DB2 server, grant appropriate database or table privileges to that user, then change the user name in Worklight.

Comment: Thanks.  Do we have a detail steps guide on what privileges needed?  And how to change the user name in Worklight?